# firefox issue with pixels and height

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have developed site www.alterway.ge . Sky image has problems above 1920 resolution. It has spaces from left and right. in Opera and Chrome it is working fine. please check my site mentioned above and help.

Comment: i'm curious to know how does it work in opera/chrome? Does the image stretch or repeat or how is it supposed to look?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs in all browsers.  When the window width is greater than your background image's width (1920px in this case) there will always be white space on either side.  You have a few options:

- use a media query to set the `background-size` to `100% auto` when the window is greater than 1920px (will cause clipping at the bottom though)
- set the `background-color` to something other than white or transparent
- set `background-repeat` to `repeat-x`

Comment: but screen width is 1920px. and image width is 1920px too. why it streches in opera/chrome and not streches in firefox?

Comment: @GioNebieridze I notice the same behavior across all the browsers.  That is, when the window's width is above 1920px, white space begins to show on both sides of the image.